# UWP Object reference not set to an instance of an object when adding item to Azure easy table

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I have a popup window that takes in input from a user and then should send it to a model which then POSTS it to an azure easy table. When I build the project everything runs fine until I hit the submit button then the app crashes and I get the Null Exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

XAML for input:

```
<Popup x:Name="ppup" IsOpen="False" IsLightDismissEnabled="True"  
 Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Popup.ChildTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <!--<EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left" />-->
                <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Left" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.ChildTransitions>
        <Grid Width="380" Height="{Binding ElementName=flyoutPane, Path=Height}"  Background="{ThemeResource FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
                <TextBlock Name="NameText" Text="Enter Name:"/>
                <TextBox  Name="NameBox" Width="200" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Name="SetsText" Text="Enter Sets:"/>
                <TextBox  Name="SetsBox" Width="200" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Name="TimeText" Text="Enter Time to complete:"/>
                <TextBox Name="TimeBox" Width="200" Height="50"/>
                <Button Name="SubmitBtn" Height="30" Width="100" Content="Submit" Click="SubmitBtn_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

C# for handling input and passing it to model:

```
CombatTableView ctv = new CombatTableView();

private async void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrillItem drillItem = new DrillItem();
        String Name = NameBox.Text;
        int Sets = Int32.Parse(SetsBox.Text);
        int Time = Int32.Parse(TimeBox.Text);
        await ctv.combatDrillsTable.AddDrill(drillItem, Name, Sets, Time, parameters);
        ppup.IsOpen = false;
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Your message here");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

View Model:

```
 class CombatTableView
{
    public CombatDrillsTable combatDrillsTable { get; set; }

    public CombatTableView()
    {
        this.combatDrillsTable = new CombatDrillsTable();
    }
}
```

Model for interacting with database:

```
public async Task AddDrill(DrillItem drillItem, String n, int s, int t, string sty)
    {
        drillItem.Name = n;
        drillItem.Sets = s;
        drillItem.SetTime = t;
        drillItem.Style = sty;

        await App.MobileService.GetTable<DrillItem>().InsertAsync(drillItem);
        drills.Add(drillItem);
    }
```

Comment: Where? Where does it throw that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a null value inside combatDrillsTable and the list that was to hold the objects null too because i hadn't put anything into my easy table at that stage so it was throwing a null exception.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was due to a checkbox accidentally bound to the event instead of the property:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsActive" Checked="{Binding IsActive}" />
```

instead of

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsActive" IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}" />
```

Comment: Remember that code blocks are made with 4 spaces (or select code then CTRL+K). I've fixed your answer.